# Date Range Picker Showing endDate on both calendars

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap date picket plug in downloaded from https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/ it works great but the problem is both calendars shows same month 10/19/2014 (October 2014). I want to show Jan 2014 (01/10/2014) for 'from' date calendar and October 2014 (10/19/2014) for 'to' date calendar.

```
$('.input-daterange').datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: '01/10/2014',
            endDate: '10/19/2014'
});
```

Code Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/o2rq93x0/2/

Comment: According to the docs, `startDate` and `endDate` set's the range of available dates. If you want to set the dates you use `setDate` and it should accept an array for datepickers with multiple fields

Comment: Try this instead -  http://stackoverflow.com/a/32554467/104380

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop through the different input fields if you want different configuration for each input. Having 2 inputs in your selector is not going to figure out `startDate` and `endDate`, divided over two datepickers, automatically. Each datepicker has it's own range between `startDate` and `endDate`, so you should program like that.

```
$('.input-daterange input').each(function(){/*set configuration here*/});
```

To have an easy system to configure your instances of datepicker, you can use `data-` attributes.

```
<input type="text" class="input-small form-control" name="start" data-date="01/11/2014" data-start="01/10/2014" data-end="10/18/2014" />
```

Then simply loop over each input and use the `data-` as your configuration.

Since you are working in the past, and the datepicker by default sets the current month as entry point, you can force the value like so:

```
input.val('10/19/2014').datepicker('update');
```

**[See a working example...](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/ow40hkdh/)**

Using:

- data-start="01/19/2014"
- data-end="10/18/2014"
- data-date="01/19/2014"

... or however you want to configure it.