# Bootstrap date range picker view month and year only

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker, daterangepicker

i build a form that contain month range. i am using daterangepicker bootstrap to do it. For example from Jan to April, but i cannot display month view only  using viewMode: 'months', or may be there is another code to display month only?

This is my js code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#growthrange').daterangepicker({
        format: 'MM/yyyy',
        viewMode: 'months',
        minViewMode: 'months',
        autoclose: true,

        locale: {
            applyLabel: 'Apply Date',
            fromLabel: 'First Date',
            toLabel: 'Second Date',
            monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
            firstDay: 1
        }
    },
    function (start, end) {
        $('#growthrange span').html(start.toString('MMMM, yyyy') + '-' + end.toString('MMMM, yyyy'));
    });
```

Help please!

Comment: I suggest - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32554467/104380

Comment: have you checked this one? https://codepen.io/nathanfiscus/pen/qELYjG

Answer (score 0):

**How about**

This code:

```js
 $("#growthrange").daterangepicker( {
        format: "mm-yyyy",
        viewMode: "months", 
        minViewMode: "months"
    });
```

Comment: That looks more like bootstrap-datepicker than bootstrap "date _range_ picker"

Comment: The bad thing with bootstrap-datepicker is that it provides 2 distinct dropdown calendar for choosing a range, instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#growthrange").daterangepicker( {
   locale: {
      format: 'MM/YYYY'
   }
})
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.