# How to show month and year only in the daterangepicker plugin?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

Html

```
<input type="text" id="daterange" name="daterange" />
```

js

```
 $(function() {
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
minDate:new Date(),
singleDatePicker: true,
locale: {
format: 'MM/YYYY'
}
});
});
```

How to hide the date selection area in daterangepicker ?
Above code display the month/year in the textbox

https://jsfiddle.net/gomal/tm053uun/

Comment: add link of your plugin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [daterangepicker show year and months only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30618462/daterangepicker-show-year-and-months-only)

Answer (score 0):

Could add this to the CSS as a quick fix

```
.table-condensed thead tr:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
.table-condensed tbody {
  display: none;
}
```

This will hide the days and weeks from the popup.  Additional logic will probably be needed to prevent keyboard inputs from modifying those values.

Comment: i have multiple daterange picker in same page, i need to apply specific date range picker